Separate status code pages in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages
I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages with Identity. I use the StatusCodePages middleware in the standard way:
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?statusCode={0}");

In that razor page, I can switch on the status code to render different content for 401, 403, 404 and "other" (all other codes in range 400..599). However that gets messy; I prefer separate pages.
So instead of this:

/Pages/Error.cshtml

I want this:

/Pages/401.cshtml
/Pages/403.cshtml
/Pages/404.cshtml
/Pages/400_599.cshtml

Is that possible?
Ugly workarounds which I already know about:

I could use the URL template "/Error/{0}", but that's impractical: I'd have to define a separate page for every code in the range 400..599. I definitely cannot do this.
In the "/Pages/Error.cshtml.cs" page model class I could redirect to different pages based on the status code. I prefer not to do this, I suspect it's bad for SEO.
For the "/Error" endpoint I could use an MVC controller with views (instead of Razor Pages); the action method could return the appropriate view. Not a bad solution, but adds unnecessary complexity; I prefer a Razor Pages approach.



I want this:
/Pages/401.cshtml /Pages/403.cshtml /Pages/404.cshtml
/Pages/400_599.cshtml Is that possible?

Of course you can, just create the page in Pages folder like below:

Then use app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/{0}") in Program.cs:
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/{0}");
app.UseExceptionHandler("/500");

//app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

For the catch-all page, you can maitain the Error Pages like below:
@page "/Error/{statusCode}"
@model ErrorModel
@{
    var statusCode = HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["statusCode"];

}
@switch (statusCode)
{
    case "400":
        <h1>BadRequest</h1>
        <p>You send wrong model to this resource.</p>
        break;
    case "401":
        <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
        <p>You are not authorized to this resource.</p>
        break;
    case "403":
        <h1>Forbidden</h1>
        <p>You don't have permission to this resource.</p>
        break;
    case "404":
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The resource you are looking for could not be found.</p>
        break;
    default:
        <h1>Error @(statusCode)</h1>
        <p>An error occurred while processing your request.</p>
        break;
}

Program.cs:
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");


Thanks. I mentioned this approach above. The problem with it is that I would have to define a separate page for every code in the range 400..599. If I get a "405" error (e.g.) and that page doesn't exist, then it would redirect to 404.

I am confused for your requirement. You said in the question you prefer seperate page instead of one page Error.cshtml. But for your current said,it seems you want the catch-all page, you can create a Razor Page named 4xx.cshtml (or 400_599.cshtml) that handles all other 4xx and 5xx status codes. You can then switch on the status code in this page to render the appropriate content.

Yes I thought of that one too :-) There are a number of options, but I hoped there was a Razor Pages way to do it without hacks. For example, maybe a delegate which I can switch on status code before the redirect. I looked for something like that but I don't think it's possible. Those workarounds are probably the only options. Thanks for your advice.

Hi @lonix, i also shared the catch-all page solution for this answer. For you said redirect? The UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute middleware never do redirect operation, you can see the url in browser, it never show /Error/statuscode or /statuscode.

Regarding the update: I came to the same conclusion. A delegate would have been nice but doesn't exist, so doing the switch in the page itself is the least complicated approach. Thanks for your advice.

I hope it's not bad for SEO, but that is not too much of a problem - these are error pages after all, and one hopes they are not accessed often! :-)

as long as the catch-all page is implemented thoughtfully and provides relevant content to users, it should not have a detrimental effect on SEO. However, it's essential to monitor your website's performance and user experience, and make adjustments as needed based on analytics data and feedback.
